# Children ExpansionTile Flutter

Tags: flutter, divider

How can I remove the divider when I expand my ExpansionTile while setting Padding for it?

```
return Card(
      borderOnForeground: false,
      key: Key("${e.id}"),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          title: Text(
            e.title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(e.by),
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[ Text("${e.descendants} comments"),Icon(Icons.open_in_new)],)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here is my Screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12vRX.jpg)

Comment: This devider is `ExpansionTile` border. You can simple copy and paste all `ExpansionTile` Widget and remove from it `BorderSide(color: borderSideColor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ExpansionTile(/*youdata*/));
```

You can wrap the ExpansionTile with Theme like above to achieve this.